# Check Python Version Used in Mod_WSGI

Tags: python, django, apache, web, mod-wsgi

I can't find out which python environment is being used or install location is being used by mod_wsgi in Apache. In my apache config I didn't gave any specific venv config.

```
        ServerName 
        ServerAlias 
        DocumentRoot /home/Downloads

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Alias /static /home/Downloads/static
        <Directory /home/Downloads/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/Downloads/samples>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/Downloads>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        #WSGIDaemonProcess group python-path=/home/Downloads python-home=/home/envlin
        WSGIProcessGroup group
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/Downloads/wsgi.py
```

I removed the critical info and replaced with random info.

Here's my apache restart log

> **Apache Logs**

`Apache/2.4.46 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1j mod_wsgi/4.7.1 Python/3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations`

> **Question**

Is there any way to get which python version and install location is being used by mod_wsgi.

> **Python Path's **
> If I fetch python path's normally here's the result.

```
sys.path = [
    '/root',
    '/usr/lib/python39.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.9',
    '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3.9/dist-packages',
]
```

Comment: You actually posted that information, didn't you?

Comment: but in these dist-packages, I can't find pip installed packages which I installed from requirements.txt. Just wanted to confirm If I can get which python mod_wsgi is using or the path of the python version.

Comment: How did you install those packages? Was a virtualenv active?

Comment: pip install -r requirements.txt

Answer (score 1):

I didn't found the way directly to get mod_wsgi version, however I went in root directory as root user and ran a find command.

```
/home//Downloads/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allauth
/home//gmcwebenvlin/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allauth
/home//.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allauth
```

And tried changing variable in urls.py in all packages and worked in one.

It turn out even when we specify different config file for `SSL version` of website in Apache, Python home was picked up from the `non-SSL version` config still.